# How to send the variable value to the navigation file in php?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want to send the value to the navigation file before the navigation called in my index.php

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$bookPage = 115;

//Sending bookpage value to navigation.php
$_SESSION['bookpage'] = $bookPage;


// Here I am including the value in navigation
include 'includes/navigation.php';

// Here I am expecting output from navigation $bookPage = 115 and relative query results

?>
```

navigation.php

```
<?php
 $bookPage = $_SESSION['bookpage'];
 $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM page_categories WHERE book_page='$bookPage'";
 $pquery = $db->query($sql2);
?>
```

Note: If I use $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM page_categories WHERE book_page='115'"; in navigation.php the everything is working fine.

I am not including navigation.php in the top of index.php because I will not get results then, so I am trying this but still not working.

Comment: you have a missing quote in the query.

Comment: @ Funk Forty Niner, Sorry it is a typing error here. In my code quote  is there at the end.

Comment: do you have the db connection included?

Comment: Btw; there should not be a space between `@` and username. I noticed you tried pinging others in another question; they didn't get the notification(s). I only got yours because I was the only person in here at the time.

Comment: @kholy, if I use WHERE book_page='1'; then the query executed.

Comment: Please fix the missing quote. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and use `mysqli_error($db)` on the query; tell us what those produce?

Comment: @ Funk Forty Niner, Thanks for the reply. Kindly check my updated questions Note.

Comment: again; no space `@member` and not `@ member`. I may not always be present here. I also asked about using 2 error handlers.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner, okay now I got your username space point. Actually I was checking username space in my database. I thought you were saying  about my database username.